# Json.NET deserialize array into property

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Is there a way to deserialize a JSON array directly into the property of an object?

I have a JSON consisting of an array of `Entry` objects. To get them into a `Collection` class I could go the route of:

```
var coll = new Collection();
coll.Entries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Entry>>(json);
```

Is there a way to define Collection in a way to skip this step an directly call `var coll = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Collection>(json)`

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try to let `Collection` implement `IEnumerable<Entry>` and see if that works.

Comment: If yor json is array of `Entry` objects why it deserialize to object? deserliazation should do same object structure as source.

Comment: @BWA the request path for the JSON is named in a way that implies getting a collection/single object back, so I want to stick with that.

Comment: Show examples of JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [silkfires answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48403410/3636680) didn't work for me, it gave me a hint for the solution:

I added the `[JsonArray]` attribute and implemented `ICollection<Entry>` by pointing all methods to the Entries list.

```
[JsonArray]
public class Collection: ICollection<Entry>
{

    public LinkedList<Entry> Entries { get; } = new LinkedList<Entry>();

    public void Add(Entry item)
    {
        Entries.AddLast(item);
    }
...
```

Comment: I could have been a bit off. If you remove the `JsonObject` attribute, does it work then?

Comment: I get a `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException :Cannot create and populate list type` for that.

Comment: Which type is it referring to?

Comment: The Collection type.

Comment: Could be I'm confusing those two attributes. Does my code work with `JsonArray` instead?

Comment: @silkfire I added a comment to your answer above. With your solution (and my edits) I did not have to implement the `ICollection` interface, which is much nicer I think.

Answer (score 2):

You could let your `Collection` class implement `IEnumerable<Entry>` and decorate it with the `JsonObject` attribute. This should give Json.NET the ability to deserialize your class correctly.

```
[JsonObject]
public class Collection : IEnumerable<Entry>
{
    public IEnumerable<Entry> Entries { get; };

    public GetEnumerator() {
       return Entries.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
       return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works if you change `[JsonObject]` to `[JsonArray]` and add a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<Entry>`. So, like `public Collection(IEnumerable<Entry> entries) { this.Entries = entries; }`. (Oh, and adding a `set;` to the Entries property.)