# Parse Json Array of Strings to Object C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, json.net

I'm working with a legacy system that is using a Generic Method to Deserialize Json Responses to Objects using Newtonsoft.Json  as Follows:

```
  responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(responseData);
```

I'm trying to deserialize this response:

```
[
"LA1_1200099253",
"LA1_1200030493",
"LA1_1200005581",
"LA1_1199533163",
"LA1_1199521680",
"LA1_1199500161",
"LA1_1199445213",
"LA1_1199385918",
"LA1_1198691674",
"LA1_1198584599",
"LA1_1198580864",
"LA1_1198199891",
"LA1_1198193839",
"LA1_1197677005",
"LA1_1197387180",
"LA1_1197178604",
"LA1_1197195621",
"LA1_1197149865",
"LA1_1197164149",
"LA1_1197050213"
```

]

But I'm getting this exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

When trying to map the response to this class:

```
  public class MatchesResponse : ResponseBase
    {
        public List<string> Games { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    }
```

Does anyone know what I could do?.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: do you mean `DeserializeObject<string[]>`?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var response = new MatchesResponse 
{
  Games = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(responseData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If responseData is a JSON string as in your example, then result can't be a responseData as well. You should rename it to something else in the first place. Simply you can user string[]:

```
string responsedata = [
"LA1_1200099253",
"LA1_1200030493",
"LA1_1200005581",
"LA1_1199533163",
"LA1_1199521680",
"LA1_1199500161",
"LA1_1199445213",
"LA1_1199385918",
"LA1_1198691674",
"LA1_1198584599",
"LA1_1198580864",
"LA1_1198199891",
"LA1_1198193839",
"LA1_1197677005",
"LA1_1197387180",
"LA1_1197178604",
"LA1_1197195621",
"LA1_1197149865",
"LA1_1197164149",
"LA1_1197050213"
]; 
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(responseData);

foreach(string s in result)
{
   Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

deserialize object allows us to parse our c# properties into a json object. if the expressions you define in the array correspond to the object, you can use this method `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<"Class Name">>(json);`

Comment: This will not work as the class the OP has listed has a property called games which does not exist in the json.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this answer helped be to solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48404221/11212251

For your case it would look like this:

```cs
[JsonArray]
public class MatchesResponse : ICollection<string>
{
   public ICollection<string> Games { get; }

   public int Count => Games.Count();

   public bool IsReadOnly => Games.IsReadOnly;

   public void Add(string item)
   {
      Games.Add(item);
   }

   public void Clear()
   {
      Games.Clear();
   }

   public bool Contains(string item)
   {
      return Games.Contains(item);
   }

   public void CopyTo(string[] array, int arrayIndex)
   {
      Games.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
   }

   public bool Remove(string item)
   {
      return Games.Remove(item);
   }

   public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
   {
      return Games.GetEnumerator();
   }

   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   {
      return Games.GetEnumerator();
   }
}
```

```cs
var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MatchesResponse>(jsonString);
```